# Is there an SF use report that shows

Tags: discussion

Is there an SF report that shows the number of posts catagorized by buckets in reputation score?  I.E. how many posts coming users within each month with reputation values from 0-100, 100-1000, 1000-5000,5000-10000, 10000 and above.

I'd be interested to see this if it is available.  If so, how do can I get a report like this.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you couldn't get this info with the [SF data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/queries); with a bit of luck, someone will already have written one, or something like it you can adapt.

Comment: And if you can't find one and don't know / want to write one, give a holla. I'm sure I have some free time later on to try and cobble one up.

Comment: Go for it!.....................

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now.
It's not pretty, and there might be mistakes in there, I'll have to review it later.

You have to input the year, [otherwise the graph looks like a mess](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/382028/posts-per-rep-group?year=2015&PostType=1+or+posttypeid+%3D+2) (and I'm bad with graphs).
And it probably needs a few less joins...
But it's fast enough right now for ServerFault.

Fun little first thing I noticed, if you look at each year, the *0-100* group used to be the minority, it has steadily grown to be the most active group on the site.
Meanwhile the *10000+* group has been slowly declining (all-be-it much slower).

Comment: How does this split into Q & A ?

Comment: @Iain You want me to turn this into a comment?

Comment: @Iain or did I misread you and is this what you ment [Segregated in Questions  and Answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/382028/posts-per-rep-group?year=2015&PostType=2). Putting it all in one result might be a bit crowded.

Comment: I was interested in the split between Q and A - thanks for the update.

Comment: Monthly averages might allow you to show the longer term trends. The really dramatic split between people <1000 and >1000 asking questions is interesting. I think that shows the split between the cluefull and the rest.